# Why does android.content.ContentResolver.delete return an integer?

Tags: android, int, implementation, long-integer, android-contentresolver

Just wondering, is there any other reason than "because the developer decided to do so" for [`android.content.ContentResolver.delete`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#delete%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to return an integer?

Shouldn't it return a long, in case one deletes more entries than an integer can store?

Answer (score 3):

I read somewhere that 2,147,483,647 (which is also the maximal number for an int) is the maximal number an auto increase primary key column in SQLite can store. Thus, I assume that the android developers assumed that there is no scenario in which a database would store more entries.